# Removing "duplicate feature" button from QGIS attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, actions

when I enable action buttons on particular layer I always get two additional buttons in edit mode: *duplicate feature* and *duplicate feature and digitize*.
Is there any way to remove them, because they aren't very helpful at our current project (and they can be easily missclick)? I couldn't find any related option in *layer properties* so maybe there's an option to remove them in qgis options somewhere?

And by the way: after some edits on layer I usually get a duplicate of my buttons in first column (like on the screenshot below). Is it bug or a feature? And how to get rid of them also?

[image: qgis action buttons]

QGIS 3.4.x

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to hide that buttons is selecting a *Combo Box* instead of *Separate Buttons*, in the *Actions* tab from the *Layer Properties* window:

[image: GabrielDeLuca-LayerProperties-Actions-Layout-ComboBox.png]

---

> I usually get a duplicate of my buttons in first column

It seems like a bug that occurs in special cases.
I saw it in layers with repeated features, every time I hid a column of the Attribute Table.
But when closing the table and reopening it, it was solved.

Comment: I made screenshot on a test layer. In our project we have more useful buttons than one, so when i pick combo box there's more clicking and there're still those two options.

Reloading attribute table is not solving the problem, because sometimes it happen after first edit of attributes so we'll just sit and reload all day. ;) But if it's a bug, I should probably report it to the devs.